# Auto select an list by value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, list, select

I have been trying to autoselect an list by it's value with javascript but not succeded.
Could anyone help me?

This is the code:

```
<script>
$("#uppdragstyp-wrapp").val("Städning");
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573930/jquery-programmatically-select-an-option-in-select-box

Comment: When you say you've been "*trying to autoselect [a] list by [its] value*" what HTML element are you referring to? A list-element (`<li>`) within a `<ul>` or `<ol>`, or an `<option>` within a `<select>` element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your script when [document is ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) otherwise your html might not loaded fully at the moment when your script gets executed.

```
$(function () { $("#uppdragstyp-wrapp").val("Städning"); });
```